# Error while parsing csv to kafka in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to send csv data to kafka using LogStash implementing my own configuration script named test.conf.
I got this error while parsing.

```
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64 
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK 
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults 
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console 
[INFO ] 2021-05-24 19:12:08.565 [main] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.10.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.262-b10 on 1.8.0_262-b10 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"} 
[FATAL] 2021-05-24 19:12:08.616 [main] runner - An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<ArgumentError: Path "/usr/share/logstash/data" must be a writable directory. It is not writable.>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:530:in `validate'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:290:in `validate_value'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:201:in `block in validate_all'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1415:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:200:in `validate_all'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:317:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:273:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:88:in `<main>'"]} 
[ERROR] 2021-05-24 19:12:08.623 [main] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

This is the command used to run logstash.

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f test.conf
```

Here is the config file.

```
input {
  file {
     path => "/home/data/*.csv"
     start_position =>"beginning"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
        "timestamp" => "%{Date} %{Time}"
            }
    }
    
    date { match => ["timestamp", "dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"]}
    
    csv {
        remove_field => ["Date", "Time"]
    }
        
    grok {
        match => { "message" => [
            "^%{DATE:timestamp},%{NUMBER:ab},%{NUMBER:cd},%{NUMBER:ef},%{NUMBER:gh},%{NUMBER:ij},%{NUMBER:kl},%{NUMBER:mn},%{NUMBER:op},%{NUMBER:qr},%{NUMBER:st},%{NUMBER:uv},%{NUMBER:wx},%{NUMBER:yz}$"
            ]
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
            kafka {
                codec => "json"
                topic_id => "abcd1234"
                bootstrap_servers => "192.16.12.119:9092"
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Obviously there is some things wrong with your Logtsash config file and you need to add your Logstash configuration file also.

Comment: @MikaelAmidi I have added the config file.

Comment: It is not your config, look at the logs, you have a `FATAL` error in your log, `Path "/usr/share/logstash/data" must be a writable directory`. It also could not find your `logstash.yml` file, you need to use `--path.settings` in this case. Which user are you running logstash? This user needs to be able to write to the `path.data` directory.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure about the the availability of your server ip with given port(192.16.12.119) with "telnet 192.16.12.119 9092 .

after that you forgot one field in in Kafka output section, Add the group_id field in your output Kafka section such as

```html
Kafka{group_id => "35834"
topics => ["Your topic name"]
bootstrap_server => "192.16.12.199:9092"
codec => json}
```

If it doesn't worked again then change you bootstrap as "advertise type" look like below

```html
bootstrap.servers => "advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.16.12.199:9092"
```

at the end do not metion you server or system ip in internet, It's not safe ;)

Comment: Don't worry I have changed the ip :).

Answer (score 0):

Your config is not even being loaded, you have a `FATAL` error when starting logstash.

```
[FATAL] 2021-05-24 19:12:08.616 [main] runner - An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<ArgumentError: Path "/usr/share/logstash/data" must be a writable directory. It is not writable.>,
```

The user that you are using to run logstash does not have permissions to write in this directory, it needs permission to write to the `path.data` directory or logstash won't start.

Your `logstash.yml` file also is not being loaded.

```
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
```

You need first to give permissions to the user running logstash to write into the `path.data`, you can change the `path.data` in the `logstash.yml` file, then you can pass the path to that file in the command line.

Considering that you installed logstash using a package manager like `yum` or `apt`, your `logstash.yml` file will be in the directory `/etc/logstash/`.

So you need to run logstash this way:

`/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /path/to/your/config.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash/`.

In the `logstash.yml` you need to set `path.data` to a directory where the user has permissions to write.

```
path.data: /path/to/writable/directory
```